# Occasional differences in return values between JavaScript and Rust functions

Tags: javascript, rust

The following JavaScript function consistently works as expected:

```js
function getvalue(a, b, c) {
    Math.floor((a / b) % c)
}
```

When I write this in Rust and use it within JS via `wasm_bindgen`, every once in a while and seemingly randomly I get a result which is different than the value returned from the function above:

```rust
pub fn get_value(a: f32, b: f32, c: f32) -> i32 {
    ((a / b) % c).floor() as i32
}
```

Some examples:

```
a = 33339077
b = 53.32715671989507
c = 3.5454545454545454

// JS -> 3, Rust -> 2

a = 33340860
b = 53.32715671989507
c = 3.5454545454545454

// JS -> 0, Rust -> 1
```

What am I missing here, and what can be done to make the Rust function return the same value as the JS one?

Comment: JavaScript numbers are `f64`s, not `f32`. Might be a factor. What is the exact difference you noticed?

Comment: Please share some example values of `a`, `b`, `c` that lead to different results

Comment: An other possible factor is `%` does not have a consistent definition, as it depends on the semantics of division in the language. Although per the wiki both Javascript and Rust use truncated division for `%` so that should be consistent, the FP precision seems a more likely issue.

Comment: @Bergi: added some examples. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Given that these values are rather close to 3 and 1 before flooring, it seems this is indeed caused by the different fp precision you have been using

Comment: The value for `a = 33339077` is more than the maximum safe float which is `16777215`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point numbers, but your Rust function uses single-precision. If you switch to `f64` you will get the same result:

```
pub fn get_value32 (a: f32, b: f32, c: f32) -> i32 {
    ((a / b) % c).floor() as i32
}

pub fn get_value64 (a: f64, b: f64, c: f64) -> i32 {
    ((a / b) % c).floor() as i32
}

fn main() {
    println!("f32: {}", get_value32 (33339077., 53.32715671989507, 3.5454545454545454));
    println!("f64: {}", get_value64 (33339077., 53.32715671989507, 3.5454545454545454));
}
```

gives:

```
f32: 2
f64: 3
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=3757ff6db34726993432cd0a55542dd0)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this after @Bergi's comment above and this was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum safe integer for a `f32` is `16777215`. Integers above this value can not be stored exactly. See this rust code:

```rs
fn main() {
    let a:f32 = 33339077.0f32;
    println!("{a:?}");
    // Output: 33339076.0
}
```

The nearest value to `33339077` that can be represented is `33337076` so your `a` will actually be 33339076, not 33339077.

You may notice that `(33339076/b)%c` is `2.98713` while `(33339077/b)%c==3.0068869` (even when using more accurate arithmetic). When flooring one comes out to 2 and the other 3.

To fix your problem use `f64` throughout your code instead of `f32`. Note that storing `a` as a `f32` at any point will introduce the inaccuracy, converting to `f64` just before calling your function will be too late, the data is already lost.

Answer (score -5):

Well, your JS function

```js
function getvalue() {
    Math.floor((a / b) % c)
}
```

Doesn't define `a`, `b`, or `c`. And the expression `(a/b) % c` yields undefined.

But it doesn't matter, because `getvalue()` doesn't return a value — it returns, by default, undefined.

Your Rust function

```rs
pub fn get_value(a: f32, b: f32, c: f32) -> i32 {
    ((a / b) % c).floor() as i32
}
```

Assuming that `f32` is a single precision IEEE float and `i32` is a 32-bit int,
.
.
.
Well, it doesn't return a value either.

But more (and most?) importantly, all numeric values in JS are IEEE double precision floats.

See Goldberg's paper, "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"

[https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~david/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/goldberg-floating-point.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edavid/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/goldberg-floating-point.pdf)

[https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf](https://www.itu.dk/%7Esestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Also see [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic,or, Why don’t my numbers add up?](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: "*it doesn't return a value either.*" - Rust does implicitly return the last expression

Comment: I fixed the omission of not passing `a, b, c` to the JS function, thanks. However I don't understand why you say that the Rust function doesn't return a value either. They both return values, which are the same in about 95% of cases.

Comment: @Bergi,  And the fact that the function definition says:  `-> i32` means it has to return a value.